# How can I avoid high time intervals between incoming udp packets in python?

Tags: python, sockets, udp, twisted

I'm trying to send udp packets to python server on local network with minimal delay between them. The machines are connected by wifi to a router.
Currently I'm experiencing a noticeable delay between 2 incoming packets about every 8-12 packets which is unacceptable in my use case.

This is simplified version of my server and client (the behaviour is exactly the same as in full version so data processing is not a bottleneck)

server side:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor

class mainController(DatagramProtocol):
    def datagramReceived(self, data, addr):
        print(data) 

reactor.listenUDP(9234, mainController())
reactor.run()
```

client side:

```
import time
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    time.sleep(0.05)
    s.sendto(b'a', '192.168.0.122, 9234')
    time.sleep(0.05)
    s.sendto(b'b', '192.168.0.122, 9234')
    time.sleep(0.05)
    s.sendto(b'c', '192.168.0.122, 9234')
```

I tested on 3 routers, used socket module on server side and sent packets with compiled code.
Nothing helped. There are times when the lag doesn't occur for a couple minutes which is promising. I don't need every packet to arrive. Low latency is more important.
Is there anything I can do?

**Update:**

Logs from updated server:

```
0.01682591438293457
0.017333984375
0.017556190490722656
0.2058579921722412  - here the lag happens
8.58306884765625e-05 
4.00543212890625e-05
3.1948089599609375e-05
3.0994415283203125e-05
3.0040740966796875e-05
3.409385681152344e-05
3.0040740966796875e-05
2.9802322387695312e-05
3.0994415283203125e-05
3.504753112792969e-05
3.0040740966796875e-05
0.008923053741455078
0.01720905303955078
0.01634383201599121
0.016458988189697266
```

obtained with modified code:

```
class mainController(DatagramProtocol):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()
    def datagramReceived(self, data, addr):
        receiveTime = datetime.now().timestamp()
        print(receiveTime-self.timestamp)
        self.timestamp = receiveTime
```

Here are my wireshark logs:
[image]

Comment: What is a "noticeable" delay?  What is an acceptable delay?  No timings shown.  This could simply be the OS doing something else important on another thread when the sleep expires.  Sleep time is a minimum, not a guarantee.

Comment: @MarkTolone I've measured call frequency to my sending function in the actual production client. It was about 60 times a second, quite even intervals 0.015-0.017s. On the server side once every 6-15 intervals one is about 0.2s. I wrote this test client code to make sure that my actual client doesnt cause the problem. I observed the same lag pattern so Its very unlikely that both very different clients produce it (the production one is an ios app and doesnt contain any sleep).

Comment: How are you measuring the delay? First step should be to narrow down by taking network captures on client, router, server and determine where the delay gets introduced by looking at time difference between every subsequent packet.

Comment: @singhatulks @singhatulks I got ```datetime.now().timestamp()``` after every call to datagramReceived and compared it to logs from my client app (obtained in a similar manner after every call to sending function). Just like I wrote the client and server "delay" logs are nearly identical but the server has those 10x higher intervals present. I also tested with wireshark and "time since previous frame" logs look similar. I'll update the question with those logs. I'm not sure how to analyse the the router performance but I will look into that even though I'm sceptical... I tested on 3 routers.